# vue.js component not working with laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

In my `welcome.blade.php` file, I have:

```
<div id="app">
    @{{ message }}
</div>
```

And in the `app.js` file:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: "Hello"
    }
})
```

The output I'm getting is just `'{{ message }}'` and not `Hello`.

Comment: any error in console

Comment: Did you used the `npm install` and `npm run dev` commands ?

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez, why npm install in laravel ?

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez Yes I have done that.

Comment: @AkhilAravind I have two errors in the console, CSRF token not found and [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #example. I have not created any component with name example so not sure where it is coming from.

Comment: post that error and check for solution if that error is related to vuejs

Comment: The first one is associated with a form that's missing the CSRF token and the second one because you are calling the ExampleComponent at app.js file but it does not exist. Maybe you deleted it because thats a default.